# find indeterminates (which are function of time) of an expression

Tags: equation-solving

Is there a function in Mathematica so as to find the indeterminates of an expression? When I used Maple, there was the function indets. Is there a similar function in Mathematica?

Here an example where I would like to find all the indeterminates :

```
Eq=l[2]^2 == (l[
      3] (Cos[γ[1][t]] Sin[α[1][t]] Sin[β[1][t]] -
        Cos[α[1][t]] Sin[γ[1][t]]) + 
    Cos[β[0][t]] Sin[α[0][t]] y[B] + 
    Sin[α[0][t]] Sin[β[0][
       t]] (-Sin[γ[0][t]] x[B] + Cos[γ[0][t]] z[B]) - 
    Cos[α[0][t]] (Cos[γ[0][t]] x[B] + 
       Sin[γ[0][t]] z[B]) - x[0][t] + 
    x[P][t]^2) + (l[
      3] (Cos[α[1][t]] Cos[γ[1][t]] Sin[β[1][t]] +
        Sin[α[1][t]] Sin[γ[1][t]]) + 
    Cos[α[0][t]] Cos[β[0][t]] y[Subscript[B, 1]] + 
    Cos[α[0][t]] Sin[β[0][
       t]] (-Sin[γ[0][t]] x[B] + Cos[γ[0][t]] z[B]) + 
    Sin[α[0][t]] (Cos[γ[0][t]] x[B] + 
       Sin[γ[0][t]] z[B]) + y[0][t] - 
    y[P][t]^2) + (-Cos[β[1][t]] Cos[γ[1][t]] l[3] + 
    Sin[β[0][t]] y[B] + 
    Cos[β[0][t]] (Sin[γ[0][t]] x[B] - 
       Cos[γ[0][t]] z[B]) + z[0][t]^2)
```

The indeterminates are functions. So it seems a bit more complicated than in the similar post "Extracting variables from an expression"

I would like to obtain all the indeterminates which are functions of time :

```
{γ[1][t], α[1][t], β[1][t], γ[0][t], α[0][t], β[0][t],x[0][t],y[0][t], z[0][t]}
```

Comment: Have you seen [Indeterminate and Infinite Results](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IndeterminateAndInfiniteResults.html)

Comment: Yes, but may be not enough deeply. In fact, I would like to obtain x,y,z if I have a function f[x,y,z] by doing a function like that Indeterminates[f[x,y,z]]. But it seems that it doesn't work.

Comment: Please supply sample code and edit your question to include that and as much detail as possible. Otherwise, this question will remain unclear.

Comment: `Cases[f[x, y, g[z]], _Symbol, Infinity]`

Comment: You should be able to to adapt the pattern in the linked Q&A. Try `f_[x_][t]  ` instead of `_Symbol` or similar.

Comment: @YvesKlett
 Here a example :
Cos[\[CapitalPsi][t]]+Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 1][t]+Subscript[x, 1][t]=0

I would like to obtain the following inderminates from this expression :
{\[CapitalPsi][t]],Subscript[\[Theta], 1][t],Subscript[x, 1][t]}

The code should work with inderminates with the following forms :
x_[t]
Subscript[x_, y_][t]
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @Louis if you have ideas, i would be interested